# How to run and debug a code on a remote machine?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I have written a software in C#.NET using Visual Studio. After all, I made a setup file and gave it to some people to install on their systems and use. The problem is in here: they run the software on their systems and get some errors while they are working with the software. there is no way for me to understand what the problem is for?

For example, if I get the error on my own system I can easily use the visual studio to debug the code and find the source of errors. But for others, currently, I have to connect to their systems remotely using software like Teamviewer, upload my code somewhere and once I connected to them, download the code from their system. Run the visual studio on their system and then open my project there and finally debug the project.

It does work. However it seems to me that it is not the best possible way to do such a work. (because, for instance, I have to download my project from their system and they can access my source code.)

Is there any other solution for running a project on the remote machine in order to debug the project?

Comment: Usually you'd want to create a log file when unhandled exception occur. This way you can see the stack trace & the exception received. [How to catch every unhandled exceotion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Comment: @TzahMama I have no problem with receiving the exceptions. But I want to debug the code on the remote machine the same way as debugging the code on mine. In such a way, I will be able to set checkpoints and debug the code in the way that I would like to.

Comment: If you want the full debug power of Visual Studio you'll have to use Remote Debugger. However, you should consider this as a last resort especially if the people you are giving your program to are _your clients_.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Visual Studio Remote Debugger - it is found in the VS installation DVD, and what you have to do with it is:

1. Copy the remote debugger to  a share on your dev machine that is visible to the client machine.
2. find the share from the client machine and run it.
3. Open VS on your machine, and from Debug -> Attach to process select the client machine (in Qualifier combo box).

This way you do not have to install or download code to the client machine.
I hope this helps.